# How to dedect if custom field contains a mp4 file in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

```
$video = get_post_meta($post->ID,'video_url', true); //default custom field
```

above is the custom field called video_url but its not allways a video format so I want to dedect first if its a video formar and Im using the following code:

```
$mimetypes = array('video/mov', 'video/flv', 'video/avi', 'video/avi', 'application/ogg', 'video/webm', 'video/mp4');

if (!empty($video) && in_array($video, $mimetypes) ) {
        echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
  }
```

the shortcode will play it in html 5 video player.So when I remove `&& in_array($video, $mimetypes)` it plays fine but I want to dedect first if its a mp4 or not.

Is it possible to do it in wordpress?
Thankyou.

Comment: try to use `strpos()` or another php string search function

Comment: yes I have tried it too maybe I used in a wrong way but didn't work.

Comment: If your variable $video give a URL of a video then you can explode() funcion it with "." and find the file type from it and if mp4 is found then process your request thereafter.

Comment: as I said above if I use only `if (!empty($video) ) {` without the `&& in_array($video, $mimetypes) ` the video works fine but I have to dedect it first because of some other iframe codes given in the same metabox everything works fine the only thing is this..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `strpos()` or another php string search function.
`in_array()` doesn't works correct, cause, for example, your `$video` looks like so:

> www.site.com/videos/video.mp4

And you `$mimetypes` array doesn't have this string inside

After that, your code will be so:

```
if (!empty($video) && strpos($video, 'mp4') !== false ) {
        echo do_shortcode( $shortcode );
  }
```

Comment: yes exactly it can be an external or internal video like that. http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4

Comment: Warning: strpos(): needle is not a string or an integer in

Comment: thankyou very much everything is working fine I appreciate your help Oleg.

Comment: Remember that anyone can change a file extension though. Someone could have a `.jpg` and rename it to `.mp4` which will pass this test while it's not actually a video file.

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese you can try to use `strpos()` in foreach loop

Comment: yes however this is a metabox where I can also add iframe codes has also the oembed function but only this one was giving me issues now everything looks fine.

Comment: @AlbanoAlbanese if this answer was helpful you can checks it as accepted. Have a nice day.)